# How to prevent unauthorized access of an API created for Twilio webhook

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, twilio, aws-api-gateway

I have to process all the inbound messages of a Twilio account using the AWS lambda function and forward it to another number. So, I have created a POST API using Amazon API Gateway and configured it on Twilio SMS webhook configurations. For any inbound SMS, Twilio is creating an event and calling the API. The API Gateway is calling the Lambda function in turn. It's all working fine.
But the problem is that Twilio only supports public APIs for webhook as far I know. So, I have to keep the API public. I am looking for some way to prevent unauthorized access.

I have looked into two approaches -

1. **Whitelisting the Twilio IP ranges:** This seems to be not possible, as Twilio's IP addresses are variable.
2. **Validating Requests are coming from Twilio inside the Lambda function:** Twilio documentation is also suggesting this approach - https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security. But with this, the Lambda function has to be executed every time, even for the invalid requests.

So, I am wondering if there is any other way to prevent unauthorized access without executing the Lambda function.

Comment: Why not use Twilio Functions? It has this capability built in.

Comment: @Alan Thanks for your reply. There are several reasons I am not using Twilio Functions. 1. It only supports Node js and I have to use Golang. 2. It is currently available as a beta release. 3. I am using AWS Lambda free tier plan, So, I don't want to spend for Twillio functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio will sign all inbound requests to your application with an `X-Twilio-Signature` HTTP header.

Twilio uses the parameters sent in the webhook (either GET or POST) and the exact URL your application supplied to Twilio to create this signature. The signature uses the `HMAC-SHA1` hashing algorithm with your Twilio account's auth token as the secret key.

Your application can verify that this signature is correct using the server-side Twilio SDKs (`validateRequest` method) or implementing your own validator ([see this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests)). You will need your account's auth token, the value of the X-Twilio-Signature HTTP header Twilio passed to you, the URL Twilio sent the webhook to and all of the parameters sent by Twilio.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am also wondering if it is the only way to authorize. I was trying to avoid this way because with this Lambda have to be executed even for the invalid requests which will affect the bill. Is it possible to authorize it from the API Gateway itself?

Comment: You can [enable request validation in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-request-validation.html) (this prevents the Lambda from running when a request is not valid) but I think it doesn't allow you to implement custom validation logic. You can create basic validation like make sure the `X-Twilio-Signature` HTTP header is included and non-blank. Please accept my answer if I helped you :)

Comment: Right, I haven't thought of it. Thanks. Also, I am exploring [Lambda Authorizer][1] for authorizing before invoking the actual Lambda. Along with this I can also enable `Request Validation` to filter the requests before invoking the `Lambda Authorizers`.


  [1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html